# I have array of products in mysql column! How to retrieve each value in Laravel

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

I have saved record in Json Format in mysql column: 
Example

```
[
 {submenu_name:Hotdogs, quantity:3, price:199},
 {submenu_name:CHEESE CROISSANT, quantity:1, price:12},
 {submenu_name:Cakes, quantity:1, price:199}
]
```

Now how to retrieve these values against each item?

Comment: Convert it into array and filter your values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am missing the "" in the key and value. Its the json syntax.

```
[
 {"submenu_name":"Hotdogs", "quantity":"3", "price":"199"},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravels Query Builder provides a convenient way of querying JSON data in table columns.

Refer to the [Laravel Query Builder documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#json-where-clauses)